# Why is em not behaving as defined

Tags: html, css

I may be new to `em` in **CSS**, but the following example seems strange...

Docs say that 1em is equal to the font-size. Everything in my example is default. So `8em` should be the size of 8 lines of text, correct?

```css
#my-div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 8em;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
  One<br/>
  Two<br/>
  Three<br/>
  Four<br/>
  Five<br/>
  Six<br/>
  Seven<br/>
  Eight
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q8vs7r4u/1/

There are 8 lines, but `8 em` only covers 7 of them. It seems that `1em` is only covering 7/8 of a line, or something...

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your line height by default is probably more than 1, try setting line-height: 1em

Comment: The only thing I would add to the answers below is to use a unitless value for `line-height`. In other words, instead of `line-height: 1em`, just use `line-height: 1`. For the reasoning, see [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Prefer_unitless_numbers_for_line-height_values).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not working because the `line-height`. On the Mozilla Developer Network you can find the following information about the default value of the `line-height`:

> Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's font-family.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

On the following code, the `line-height` will be reset to `1em` and the whole text fits the `div`:

```css
div {
  background-color:red;
  height:8em;
  line-height:1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  One<br/>Two<br/>Three<br/>Four<br/>Five<br/>Six<br/>Seven<br/>Eight
</div>
```

**From the official W3C specification:**

> Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based on the font of the element. The value has the same meaning as . We recommend a used value for 'normal' between 1.0 to 1.2. The computed value is 'normal'.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height

But every user agent (browser) defines the height of `line-height` itself on the recommended value between 1.0 and 1.2!

Comment: While @Quentin 's answer was straight to the point, I appreciated the doc reference on why it behaves this way, and the example on how to solve it. This answered both my questions. Thanks!

Comment: @Partik Just for the record, MDN is not the official specification. It is a crowd-sourced documentation network, but each page *should* link to **the** official specification toward the bottom.

Comment: @TylerH - added the official description of the value

Answer (score 33):

The default `line-height` is not `1` so each line is taller than the font-size of the text inside it.

Answer (score 11):

The height of a [line box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting) is **not** determined by [`font-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-styling). Or not directly, at least.

You can see the [detailed rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height) in the spec. When a line box only contains non-replaced inline boxes with the same [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) and [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align), those rules say that the height of the line box will be given by the [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) of the inline boxes.

This applies to your case, because text directly contained inside a block container element is wrapped in an [anonymous inline box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous).

If you don't set [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) to any explicit value, the height of the line box will be given by the initial value of [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height), `normal`, which behaves like this:

> Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based
>   on the font of the element. The value has the same meaning as
>   [<number>](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-number). We recommend a used value for 'normal' between 1.0 to
>   1.2. The [computed value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#computed-value) is 'normal'.

For example, if the browser chooses `1.15`, `1em` will cover `1/1.15 = 0.8696` of the height of the line. That is so close to the `7/8 = 0.8750` you observed.

Note anonymous inline boxes inherit inheritable properties like [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) from the block parent box. Then, you can set the [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) of the block to an explicit length, and the height to that length multiplied by the number of lines.

```css
#my-div {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: calc(1.2em * 8);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div">One<br/>Two<br/>Three<br/>Four<br/>Five<br/>Six<br/>Seven<br/>Eight</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Specify a `line-height` of `1em` to see the expected results:

```
div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 8em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> 1em is equal to the font-size

*Horizontally.* Not vertically. The em is the width of an 'm'. It isn't valid typographically to use it for vertical spacing.

Comment: See [relative units](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#x34). `em` is defined as "the [`font-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-size) of the relevant font". You can use that unit everywhere a [<length>](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-length) is expected. Including vertical, diagonal or whatever.

Comment: @Oriol I'm talking about how to do typography, and a definition of the em that is several hundred years older than w3c.org. No typographer since Gutenberg would use an em for vertical spacing. He would use the font height.